# My Menu in Java can't be Called Twice?

Tags: java, swing, menu, applet, jframe

I'm new to java and programming in general, and I am writing a program that has a menu in it. (It is a JFrame in java) What it does is when you hit a JButton, it shows an applet on the screen. When the applet is done, it goes to a screen where you can choose to run the applet again or go back to the main menu when you hit a button. The problem is that when you hit the button to go back to the menu, it doesn't. All it does is make neither button clickable.
This is the method I use to draw the menu:

```
public static void drawMenu()
{
    f.add(BOption1);
    f.add(BOption2);
}
```

The two jbuttons are already declared and such in the constructor, and they work fine the first time I run the menu.  Then, when you hit one of the buttons, it removes both buttons from the screen with f.remove(...).  Does anyone know why it won't work when I call this method a second time?

Edit:
Sorry, I meant to say canvas, not applet.

Edit Edit:
I found the solution to my problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Regarding, `"Sorry, I meant to say canvas, not applet."`: this is still unclear. What do you mean by "canvas"? Do you mean a Canvas object? A compiler is strict and unforgiving with regards to spelling, capitalization and syntax, and you should be likewise when asking questions here.

Comment: Glad you've got it solved. For the benefit of all, please share the cause of the problem and your solution with all. Note that I still stand by my recommendations posted in my answer below, that you've got serious problems with your program that can be helped (somewhat) by my recommendations.

Comment: The problem(I believe) was that I was removing the JButtons from the frame and then adding them, so instead I made then not visible with setVisible(false).  Then I did f.add(...) again when I needed to make them appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your main class, Frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

   static OnePlayer onePlayer;
   static TwoPlayer twoPlayer;

   static Frame f;
   static JButton BOnePlayer = new JButton("Single Player");
   static JButton BTwoPlayer = new JButton("Multiplayer");
   static JButton BInstructions = new JButton("Instructions");
   static JButton toMenu;
   static JButton replay;

   public Frame(String name) {
      super(name);
      this.setTitle(name);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setSize(640, 673);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setResizable(false);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setLayout(null);
      this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

      BOnePlayer.setBounds(120, 150, 400, 100);
      BTwoPlayer.setBounds(120, 250, 400, 100);
      BInstructions.setBounds(120, 350, 400, 100);

      BOnePlayer.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 20));
      BTwoPlayer.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 20));
      BInstructions.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 20));

      BOnePlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container onePane = f.getContentPane();
            onePane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            onePlayer = new OnePlayer();
            onePane.add(onePlayer);
            onePlayer.init();

            f.remove(BOnePlayer);
            f.remove(BTwoPlayer);
            f.remove(BInstructions);
         }
      });
      BTwoPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container twoPane = f.getContentPane();
            twoPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            twoPlayer = new TwoPlayer();
            twoPane.add(twoPlayer);
            twoPlayer.init();

            f.remove(BOnePlayer);
            f.remove(BTwoPlayer);
            f.remove(BInstructions);
         }
      });
      BInstructions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         }
      });
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      f = new Frame("Snake");
      drawMenu();
   }

   public static void OnePlayerDone(int score) {

   }

   public static void TwoPlayerDone(int winner, int p1score, int p2score) {
      f.remove(twoPlayer);

      replay = new JButton("Play Again");
      toMenu = new JButton("Return to Menu");

      replay.setBounds(120, 100, 400, 100);
      toMenu.setBounds(120, 500, 400, 100);

      replay.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 20));
      toMenu.setFont(new Font("Comic Snas MS", Font.ITALIC, 20));

      f.add(replay);
      f.add(toMenu);

      replay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container twoPane = f.getContentPane();
            twoPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            twoPlayer = new TwoPlayer();
            twoPane.add(twoPlayer);
            twoPlayer.init();
         }
      });
      toMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawMenu();
         }
      });
   }

   public static void drawMenu() {
      f.add(BOnePlayer);
      f.add(BTwoPlayer);
      f.add(BInstructions);
   }
}
```

Suggestions:

- First off, rename your class to something other than `Frame`. This is the name of a closely related core Java class, the AWT equivalent of JFrame, and your giving it the same name can confuse many. Perhaps call it `SnakeFrame`.
- All of your static variables should instead be instance variables.
- You shouldn't even have a SnakeFrame variable (your variable f). Instead you should use the current SnakeFrame instance, the `this` if you will.
- Don't mix AWT with Swing components unnecessarily and without need. For instance you should use no Canvas-derived objects but rather JPanel-derived objects.
- Your code should follow Java naming conventions so that others (us for instance) can understand it. Variable and method names should all begin with a lower case.
- You will want to read up on and use the layout managers to help you place your GUI components on your GUI rather than use null layout and `setBounds(...)`.
- Most important, to swap views as you're trying to do, read up on and use a CardLayout as this was built for just this purpose.

Comment: +1 for reminding not to use `null` layout (and all other good advices)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer and will be deleted, but I needed to post a more complex comment:

> I am writing a program that has a menu in it. (It is a JFrame in java) What it does is when you hit a JButton, it shows an applet on the screen.

Can you explain why you're doing this? It is most unusual and difficult for a JFrame to display an applet as an applet. Are you doing this by launching the applet using some stand-alone applet viewer? Perhaps you're doing something else, such as displaying a dialog or another JFrame, but using the wrong terms to describe it?

> When the applet is done, it goes to a screen where you can choose to run the applet again or go back to the main menu when you hit a button.

How do you achieve this? What code do you use?

> The problem is that when you hit the button to go back to the menu, it doesn't. All it does is make neither button clickable.  This is the method I use to draw the menu:

```
public static void drawMenu()
{
  f.add(BOption1);
  f.add(BOption2);
}
```

> Does anyone know why it won't work when I call this method a second time?

Somehow your code is changing the state of your program and thereby makes your JButtons unresponsive. How it's doing this -- you haven't told us enough for us to say.

I'm not sure that we have enough information to answer your question yet. Please show more code and give us more detailed and precise description of what is going on. Best would be if you could post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Do you need to see the code itself, or do you want me to explain more about how it works?

Comment: @user2371168: we would be best served if you could create an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please see link.

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/zqhntYt7s0/

Comment: that hyperlink above is a link to my sscce(i hope it works, i never tried this website before)

Comment: @user2371168: What you've posted is not an sscce. Please have another look at the link that Andrew and I provided you. The first letter, "s" stands for "short". An SSCCE should be at most 100 lines of code only, it should compile and run and demonstrate your problem. The link explains all and explains it well. You should be able to post the full code of your SSCCE here in your question. Also many folks (myself included) do not trust the download sites such as you're suing.